# What is the use of __name__ == "__main__" in python?

Tags: python

I tried using `__name__ == "__main__"` in my python program, but didn't understand it properly.
Below is my code block:

```
def main():
  print 'hello'
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/1355555

Comment: If I run this program, I get "hello" as output. What do you mean by your program "didn't understand it properly?" Make sure when asking a question you include both your input (which you have), AND your current and expected output. See the "related tips" in [ask] for more info.